# How to import only unique primary key rows in postgresql from a csv file?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have to generate the same report everyday in excel in csv format. Most days, the report spits out the same information/rows (based off a primary key id). If there is a new key row however, my job is to identify it.

I want to import this data into postgresql. However, since the report is basically the same everyday, how can I make it so that whenever I import the report in the database, it only imports new unique primary keys?

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you want to load data.

If you build insert query, then [ON CONFLICT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) is good option

```sql
INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE
```

If you can first load file into temporary table (temp_table) then in second step:

```sql
insert into dest_table
select * from temp_table 
   where not exists (select 1 from dest_table where dest_table.id = temp_table.id)
```